# Opening macro security from VBA on startup

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a code that on startup checks if the option "Trust access to the VBA project object model" is enabled or not.

In the case that it is not enabled, I need the program to open the macro security settings for easy access for the user.

I've made some code that does this in most cases, but I've encountered one problem that I don't know how to get around.

The code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open
If Not VBATrusted() Then
    MsgBox "Trust access to the VBA project object model is not enabled" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "Please allow access by ticking the checkbox in the window that appears after clicking Ok"
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("MacroSecurity")
End If
End Sub

Function VBATrusted() As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    VBATrusted = (Application.VBE.VBProjects.Count) > 0
End Function
```

This code does its job unless the macro settings are as default "Disable all macros with notification", in which case I activate the macro and then get a run-time error "-2147467259 (80004005) Method 'ExecuteMso' of object '_CommandBars' failed"

This error will only occur on the first startup, as I do not have to activate the macros on consecutive startups, unless I move the file location.

I've tried pausing the macro for two seconds, but that did nothing for me, and neither did an error handler that tried to grab the error and then try executing the `Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("MacroSecurity")` line again. It ended up with the same error.

The debugger tells me that the error is in the `Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("MacroSecurity")` line, but that's probably not much of a surprise with that error message.

Comment: Have you considered instead of pausing 2 seconds, setting an `Application.OnTime` event that fires in 2 seconds?

Comment: I've tried things like this in the past and it's not easy - it's been made hard for a reason, to prevent malicious code from running on the user's computer. While I'm sure it's possible to do this, I've never been able to find a viable solution myself.

Comment: @dwirony see a few solutions below :)

Comment: Well, this is a first. All answers are useful and works, but the one I like the most is not an answer, but a comment :) Thank you all for the suggestions

Comment: @DavidZemens When I needed it, I was working with Word VBA, and my case was a little different - I was trying to bring up the STARTUP folder to allow the user to drag and drop a file into it, but it seemed hard to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple solution** as proposed by @CLR in comments above, but didn't work when I initially tested it (user error!). All code goes in `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
If Not VBATrusted() Then
    MsgBox "Trust access to the VBA project object model is not enabled. " & vbNewLine & _
    "Please allow access by ticking the checkbox in the window that appears"
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "ThisWorkbook.SetSecurity"
End If
End Sub

Function VBATrusted() As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    VBATrusted = (Application.VBE.VBProjects.Count) > 0
End Function

Sub SetSecurity(Optional foo)
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "MacroSecurity"
End Sub
```

**Slightly more elaborate:** Add an `MSForms.CommandButton` to the worksheet which will open the security settings pane after user clicks it. Have the `MsgBox` prompt the user to click the button and then change the security settings.

In `Module1`, the Button's click event handler:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Button1_Click()
    Call ThisWorkbook.SetSecurity
End Sub
```

In `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
If Not VBATrusted() Then
    MsgBox "Trust access to the VBA project object model is not enabled. " & vbNewLine & _
    "Please allow access by:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "1. Clicking the button on this sheet" & vbNewLine & _
    "2. Ticking the checkbox in the window that appears"
End If
End Sub

Function VBATrusted() As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    VBATrusted = (Application.VBE.VBProjects.Count) > 0
End Function

Sub SetSecurity(Optional foo)
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "MacroSecurity"
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a great way to get around it, though a bit more elaborate that I had hoped for. I just got around to testing the `Application.Ontime` that CLR suggested in the comment to the original post, and that actually does the trick.

Comment: Are you sure? When I tried Application.OnTime, I thought got the same error.

Comment: Ahhh. Yep, I had some wrong configuration when I tried it. I'll add that option to this answer as well.

Comment: I've made a sub in a module that contains nothing but the `Sub TrustCenter()
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("MacroSecurity")
End Sub` which is called in the Workbook_Open with this line `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "TrustCenter"` Done this way it seems to work as intended. I haven't been able to trigger the error yet at least

Comment: @ChristianEmilJohansen yes that should work, my first test I had the procedure in `ThisWorkbook` but forgot to qualify the procedure name as `"ThisWorkbook.SetSecurity"`, and it gave me a "cannot be found or disabled" error. QUalifying to `ThisWorkbook` module made it work.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking outside the box here...
What if you put a big message on the sheet which tells the user to activate macros, and then have an auto start macro delete or hide that message. That would bring the message to those who need it, but not the others.

Comment: I'm making a fully automated sheet for users who may never have used a computer in their life. Asking them to enter the settings of excel is just asking for a meltdown, so I can't do that. Trust me, I'd love to, but I cant

Comment: @ChristianEmilJohansen You can make this as elaborate as you'd like (consider a worksheet with step-by-step instructions & screenshots). Display it by default, but if `VBATrusted` then hide that sheet on the `Auto_Open` or `Workbook_Open` event so that users who are not affected, will not see it.

Comment: I should be able to make a button that when clicked runs the `Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("MacroSecurity")` in a step by step tutorial though, right? So that after hitting the "Enable Content" from Excel, all they have to do is click my button to get directy to the settings?

Comment: @ChristianEmilJohansen Seems to work when I test it. User has to Enable content, then the MsgBox is displayed. Add to the MsgBox and tell user to click the button on worksheet, then it should work.